# My .css for a rating function has some issue

Tags: html, css, web

I tried to make a rating function. I used style referencing from https://gist.github.com/blairanderson/7f9d1c08345c6573e09edaa1f7316fa1 to draw stars.

my view part is

```
<div class="rate">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" <?php echo ($postData['average_rating'] >= 5)?'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
        <label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" <?php echo ($postData['average_rating'] >= 4)?'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
        <label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" <?php echo ($postData['average_rating'] >= 3)?'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
        <label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" <?php echo ($postData['average_rating'] >= 2)?'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
        <label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" <?php echo ($postData['average_rating'] >= 1)?'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
        <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

my style part is

```
<style>
.rate {
    float:left;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
}

.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: gold;
}

.rate > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
}
</style>
```

I've checked my jquery, and it's good. From the inspector, I can see that
[image]
, but there is only the first star shown [image]. I don't know why.

Moreover, I must put style part in this file to let it work. I'm sure the other style parts in mystyle.css works well. I also don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the work is happening using the general sibling selector ([~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)) that

> matches the second element only if it follows the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent element.

...and the fact that ONLY ONE radio button in a group can be selected at a time. As per your code, you're trying to mark all the radio buttons to `checked`. And in such a scenario, only the last `checked` radio button prevails. You can see this behaviour if you comment out the radio button hiding CSS, as below.

```css
.rate {
  float: left;
}

/*.rate:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}*/

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #ddd;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #f70;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" checked="checked">
  <label for="star5"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" checked="checked">
  <label for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" checked="checked">
  <label for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" checked="checked">
  <label for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" checked="checked">
  <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

The solution would be to make sure you mark only the highest rating numbered radio button to `checked` in your PHP code, which in your case is number 5. I believe the solution would be make your PHP condition to `==` instead of `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your code, there is no issue with your styles. It is working fine without that php code.

```css
.rate {
    float:left;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" checked="checked">
        <label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" checked="checked">
        <label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" checked="checked">
        <label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" checked="checked">
        <label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" checked="">
        <label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. As other answer explains, I need to change >= to ==